# In Salesforce1 app, is it possible to create a "slide-in" page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm looking to create a screen that slide in similar to the standard look-up screen that slides in when you tap on the magnifying icon.

For example, when you tap on magnifying glasses in Branch or Merchandise, a new look-up screen will slide in.

[image]

The different is that my sliding-in would be visualforce page, or, if possible, a lightning page.

Comment: Have you tried using jquery in your VF page ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement it using a [Timing Design Token](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/tokens/#category-timing) and the using LDS [Motion](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/motion/)

They haven't shown any examples as such yet.

Also you can implement using a third party plugin (provided it works in JavaScript strict mode) as Salesforce has implemented Locker Service recently in Lightning.